# Is it possible to make area before cursor in edit text able to use paste?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In whole edittext after long press i can paste some text, but after adding left padding i can do this only after cursor (red rectangle area) and not before cursor (blue rectangle area). It is probably the way how edittext works, but is it possible to make blue area use paste ? This is just a simple example, but in my app instead of imageView i have FrameLayout.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.gordian.android.myapplication.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` with your EditText and `android:drawablePadding=""` to set an image and its padding instead of an ImageView inside RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks, but that works just with imageView. My problem is that in my app instead of image view i have Frame layout.

Comment: That works with any drawables. You can draw there anything

Comment: Ok, but i have a FrameLayout how can i add it as drawable ?

Comment: You have view inside it? Why you posted the question without your actual code?

Comment: Well i cant really paste here the code, but basically i have my own view that extends framelayout and inside i have image view and progress bar. This is right next to the edit text cursor.

Comment: check android:descendantFocusability property to pas your touch to the root and there you can focus edittext.

Comment: could you be more specific on how to do it pls ? i used descendantFocusability="beforedescendants" in my view but do not know how to focus edittext